# snakemake config PATH ENVIRONMENT

Tags: snakemake

I try to write a workflow using snakemake, but do not know how to configure PATH environment for all rules in the configure file, and did not find relational questions. Anyone can give a help?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this FAQ entry](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html?highlight=shell.prefix#i-want-to-configure-the-behavior-of-my-shell-for-all-rules-how-can-that-be-achieved-with-snakemake). However, please also consider to simply use [Conda integration](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#integrated-package-management) instead of manupulating PATH yourself.